# Looking for a word to express that a company has been around for a while

Tags: word-choice

We have thought of Heritage, Traditional, Enduring... but these words aren't "it." Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: *long-established*

Comment: What sort of company?

Comment: PressTilty, it's a construction company.

Comment: *Has* the company been around for a while? If it has, just do the [*'Est. 1534'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_University_Press) thing; it's cool.  If not, refer to yourselves as "The Original ..."

Comment: an "experienced company" ?

Comment: A construction company?  How about "longstanding"?

Comment: Stella Artois, Anno 1366. To be read as ***established** in the year of our Lord, 1366*.

Comment: *longstanding*, *notable*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **well-established**:

> having **existed for a long time**, and **having been successful** or accepted for a long time
>
> **a well-established company**/hotel

(Source: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/well-established)

I personally like how this word captures both the fact that the company has been around *and* the success it has had.

Answer (score 1):

For a situation such as this, I try to find reasons to use the word "venerable".  The Merriam-Webster has the following definition for AmE:

> 1. old and respected : valued and respected because of old age, long use, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about *venerable?* It suggests that your company is worthy of respect on account of its age.

Answer (score 0):

A company that has been around for a long while, with the "staying power" to weather the ups and downs of market conditions over the decades, is said to have **longevity**.

Answer (score 0):

“Reputable” suggests a business that has been around for long enough for its brand to be not only well-established but also well-regarded in general.

Answer (score 0):

How about **long recognized**?

> *Paterson & Dowding is a long recognized company of Family Lawyers situated in Perth* ([**Jasper 1951vr**](https://jasper1951vr.wordpress.com/))
>
> recognized: provided with a secure reputation

[**Princeton University, Farlex Inc.**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recognized)

Answer (score 0):

Some companies that have been around for a while are referred to as "institutions" or "institutions of the community."

(My only source is the spoken English I've encountered in my life.)